# Multiple form validation in angular template driven forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a large form splitted to multiple pages. In fact, in each page I have separate `<form>`. All the forms are databound to single model instance:

```
model = {
    page1Model = { input1: '', input2: '' }
    page2Model = { input3: '', input4: '' }
    ...
}
```

Example of page component html:

```
<form #page1Form>
  <label>Input1</label>
  <input id="input1" name="input1" [(ngModel)]="model.input1" required />
  ...
```

Using template driven forms, is it possible to show validation summmary for all pages in one place?

Comment: You mean it should be [(ngModel)]="model.page1Model input1", right? You can iterate errors by accessing 'page1Form.errors'.

Comment: yeah, but I need to iterate over error in all pages

Comment: Maybe you need to switch to Reactive Forms. However, if forms are in different component, I guess iterating errors is the only option.